# Cypress test optimise for multiple UI behavior

Tags: cypress

In our project we serve multiple clients with the same codebase and each client is having its own configuration, so the UI is behaving as per the configuration, the configuration is saved in the database for the UI elements, we don't want to write a separate test suite for different clients, the reason is when anything gets added to all the clients we should able to update at once in one place and it should work.

Can we get guidance on how we can structure our tests so that they will read the configuration per client from the database and behave accordingly?

Comment: The question is too broad. Read the docs on [configuration](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration), have a go and post the example code.

Comment: I am having two clients UI say client A and client B both have one registration form client A contains one section Preferences which  is having text box and radio button elements. now client B contains section Terms and conditions where it has only checkbox. I am having a configuration in the database that I can decide that Preference and Terms and condition section visibility to various clients.

Comment: I can write separate test for A and B but if something changes in the DB then I don't need to modify the tests each time. Furthermore if any new client will get added tomorrow then I don't need to write the test for that client from scratch. If a new section to be added then I can amend the tests to accommodate for all the clients